# How to programatically drop down the TcxDateEdit control calendar?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

How do you tell the `TcxDateEdit` control to dropdown the calendar on let's say a button click?

The only way I could think of is simulating key press, but that's just a backup plan.

Comment: Wouldn't `YourDateEdit.Properties.Buttons[0].Click` *hack* work ? [[wild, wild guess](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/DQ5648) :)]

Comment: buttons have no click property....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TCxDateEdit` has a `DroppedDown` property of type `Boolean`.

To drop down the calendar in a button `OnClick` event, you may do as following:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  cxDateEdit.DroppedDown := True;
end;
```